# getPictureAttribute in Laravel 5.1 Model

Tags: laravel

In my object User, I have an optional profile picture.
I would like to display it, and if it is null, set the pic to a standart avatar.png

So I thought the good place was in the model, with :

```
public function getPictureAttribute($picture){
    return is_null($picture) ? 'avatar.png' : $picture;
}
```

In my view:
The code I want to avoid

```
@if (!is_null($user->picture))
    <img src="{{  $user->picture) }}" />
@else
    <img src="{{  "avatar.png") }}"  />
@endif
```

The code I want, but that fail because it is not returning avatar.png but null

```
<img src="{{  $user->picture) }}" />
```

picture is null, I don't know why?

Anybody to explain???

Comment: try it with setPictureAttribute function

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing accessors with mutators. When you define an accessor (the attribute getter), you have to return the modified data like this:

```
public function getPictureAttribute($picture)
{
    return is_null($picture) ? 'avatar.png' : $picture;
}
```

When you define a mutator (the attribute setter), that's when you do what you have in your example except you must set it (not get it):

```
public function setPictureAttribute($picture)
{
    if (is_null($picture))
    {
        $this->attributes['picture'] = "avatar.png";
    }
    else
    {
        $this->attributes['picture'] = $picture;
    }
}
```

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

Comment: Tx, I get that. Thing is I wanted to do that to avoid doing:
@ if ($user->picture != null)
                                <img src="{{  $user->picture) }}"  />
                             @ else
                                <img src="{{  "avatar.png") }}"  />
                             @ endif
in my views. But if I use  getter, it never give me the avatar

Comment: But you defined the getter incorrectly in your example. Did you try my example?

Comment: yes, I corrected it! I use get, and return something

Comment: but in my views, I still have null pictures

Comment: That's weird. :/ Can you edit your post with the updated code?